# Deployment of containerized .Net7 WebAPI application in minikube cluster getting failed while initContainers for "dotnet ef database update"

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, kubernetes, entity-framework-core, minikube

I have created new .Net 7.0 webapi project which has Entity framework core 7 and have to deploy in local minikube cluster.
below are the project references

```
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.9" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.9">
```

**here i have docker file**

```
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["IAMHub1.csproj", "IAMHub1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "IAMHub1/IAMHub1.csproj"
WORKDIR "/src/IAMHub1"
COPY . .

RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 7.0

RUN dotnet build "IAMHub1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "IAMHub1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "IAMHub1.dll"]
e
```

here is deployment yaml for webApi app

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: iamhub-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: iamhub
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: iamhub
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: database-migration
          image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0
          command: [ "dotnet", "ef", "database", "update" ]
      containers:
        - name: iamhub-container
          image: my-username/iamhub1:latest
          env:
          - name: SQL_SERVER_CONNECTION_STRING
            valueFrom:
             secretKeyRef:
               name: xyz-secret
               key: connectionstring
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

for sql server in minikube cluster I have installed simcube/mssqlserver-2022 using below command

```
 .\helm install my-mssqlserver-2022 simcube/mssqlserver-2022 --version 1.2.3
```

my-mssqlserver-2022 is installed and running successfully in minikube cluster

**My goal here is to update database when application gets deployed**

Issue :-
After apply deployment yaml it creates deployment but container is not getting started and after investigate I got below error

1. when I describe (kubectl describe pod pod-id) it shows below events

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  32s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/iamhub-deployment-6f8857994f-8mqpw to minikube
  Normal   Pulled     15s (x3 over 32s)  kubelet            Container image "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    15s (x3 over 32s)  kubelet            Created container database-migration
  Normal   Started    15s (x3 over 32s)  kubelet            Started container database-migration
  Warning  BackOff    2s (x4 over 29s)   kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container database-migration in pod iamhub-deployment-6f8857994f-8mqpw_default
```

2. when check logs using `kubectl logs iamhub-deployment-6f8857994f-8mqpw -c database-migration`
   will get below error

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

will be good if I get to know what's wrong here and possible fix .
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your project directory (your local development machine), run the following commands:

```
dotnet new tool-manifest
dotnet tool install dotnet-ef --version 7.0
```

This will generate a `.config` directory in your project and create a `dotnet-tools.json` file inside it. And we should ensure the `.config/dotnet-tools.json` file is committed to source control. Then we can fix the `Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.` error.

The docker file:

```
# Build and publish the application using the SDK
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["IAMHub1.csproj", "IAMHub1/"]
COPY .config .config
RUN dotnet restore "IAMHub1/IAMHub1.csproj"

# Restore local dotnet tools
RUN dotnet tool restore

COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN dotnet build "IAMHub1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "IAMHub1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

# Create the final runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "IAMHub1.dll"]
```